# UPDATE si existe registro, INSERT si no existe

Tags: php, mysql, update

Tengo el siguiente código PHP donde hago un INSERT INTO:

```
$con = "INSERT INTO registroProblemaFinal (numEmpleado, nomEmpleado, cantidad, produccion, fecha, hora, turno, linea, maquina)
      VALUES ('$numE', '$nomE', '$cantidad', '$produccion', '$fecha', '$hora', '$turno', '$linea', '$maquina')";
      $query = $conexion->query($con);
```

Lo que necesito es verificar en mi base de datos si tengo un registro con la misma fecha, linea y maquina, si es así, el registro se reemplazaría con un UPDATE.

EJEMPLO:

Hago el siguiente registro: 
numEmpleado: 1 
nomEmpleado: Jose 
**fecha: 2020-04-05** 
hora: 08:09 
turno: 1ro 
**linea: linea2 

maquina: maquina1** 
cantidad: 2 
produccion 1000

Despues decido hacer el mismo registro pero con otros datos en cantidad y produccion, en este caso quisiera que se modificara mi registro anterior y no que se inserte otro, espero su respuesta y haber explicado bien, saludos!

Comment: Comentario no relacionado a tu pregunta, pero con el código compartido: el modo en que se está haciendo la inserción es inseguro y se considera una mala práctica. Deberías usar sentencias preparadas en lugar de generar el comando SQL de forma dinámica. Tal y como está el código ahora mismo es potencialmente vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es una funcion

```
funcion buscar_dato($conexion,$...){ proceso  return dato }
si buscar_dato - true 
- udpate 
else - no hacer nada
```

Answer (score 0):

pienso que lo primero que debes hacer es una consulta a la tabla a ver si el registro existe, en caso de que exista realizas el update, en caso que no, el insert, no te pongo el codigo porque imagino ya sabes como hacerlo, pero si necesitas mas ayuda avisa.

Comment: Cierto, la proxima respuesta le pongo codigo. Gracias